# Getting permission denied in heroku container login

Tags: docker, heroku, heroku-cli, heroku-ci

I was trying to deploy my `flask` backend in heroku with docker. But when I run the command

```sh
heroku container:login
```

Getting those error

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon
> socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get
> http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/version: dial unix
> /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied  ▸    Login failed
> with: 1

My `heroku.yml` file in the top level directory is

```yaml
setup:
  addons:
    - plan: heroku-postgresql
      as: DATABASE
build:
  docker:
    web: mymeds/Dockerfile
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - ./release-tasks.sh
run:
  web: python manage.py run
```

Answer (score 4):

try this, it work for me

> $ sudo heroku login && sudo heroku container:login